# Designing database for a dictionary

Tags: database, database-design

I want to make a database for English-Deutsch dictionary.

I have no idea how I would design that.

If every word had one meaning I would just had 2 databases - English words and Deutsch words - and then link them together.

Even one way solution would probably be sufficient for me. So I could query for Deutsch work and get all English words linked to it (but one English word should still be linkable to multiple Deutsch words).

So how would you do this? Am I thinking in a wrong way about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [paparazzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607314/paparazzo) provided a very definitive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37241676/1426227), I just would like to add a few more details on what your database could be like.

You could have:

- A table for English words
- A table for Deutsch words
- A join table to link these tables

See below:

```
                              +-----------------+                          
                              | TRANSLATION     |                          
                              +-----------------+                          
    +---------+       +-------| ENGLISH_ID (PK) |               +---------+
    | ENGLISH |       |       | DEUTSCH_ID (PK) |-------+       | DEUTSCH |
    +---------+       |       +-----------------+       |       +---------+
    | ID (PK) |<------+                                 +------>| ID (PK) |
    | WORD    |                                                 | WORD    |
    +---------+                                                 +---------+
```

To find the Deutsch translation(s) for an English word, use the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  d.word
FROM deutsch d
JOIN translation t
  ON d.id = t.deutsch_id
JOIN english e
  ON e.id = t.english_id
WHERE e.word = :english_word
```

To find the English translation(s) for a Deutsch word, use the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  e.word
FROM english e
JOIN translation t
  ON e.id = t.english_id
JOIN deutsch d
  ON d.id = t.deutsch_id
WHERE d.word = :deutsch_word
```

Comment: Just to make sure I get this - this means I'll have multiple 'translation' rows for single 'english' row (if needed), right? Otherwise thank you very much. This really helped me.

Comment: @DavidMašek This approach is really flexible. Among other cardinalities, it allows you to have multiple Deutsch words for one English word.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a join table with a composite key of

EnglishID, DeutschID

You can have 1:0, 0:1, 1:many, many:1, or many:many